# Load Data in fields of visual force when i click a button

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, fields, visual

I Wanna Load data in fields when i click a simple link.

I have this, but is not working

```
apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="contactFields"> 
          <apex:pageBlockSection id="UpdateElectrodependiente" columns="2" >
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!actionElectrodependiente}" reRender="contactFields" value="Cargar Datos"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection id="FirstName" columns="2">
                 <apex:inputField label="Nombre Paciente" value="{!contacto.FirstName}"></apex:inputField>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And this is my constructor and method to load data:

public class ATCL_VFC058_ElectrodependienteController {

```
public String idAccount = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');

public Contact contactoSolicitante = new Contact();  
public Contact contacto = new Contact();

public Case caso {get;set;}    

public List<Contact> Records {get; set;}

Public RecordType rt = [select Id,name from RecordType where Name ='AP' and SobjectType = 'Case'];  


public ATCL_VFC058_ElectrodependienteController() {

    this.caso=new Case();
    this.caso.Reason = 'CORTE Y REPOSICION / MOROSIDAD';
    this.caso.RecordTypeId=rt.id;
    this.contacto =contacto;//new Contact();

}       

public Contact getContacto() {
    return this.contacto;
}

public void setContacto(Contact cto) {
    this.contacto = cto;
} 
public void loadData(){
    this.contacto.LastName='HOLA';
}
```

When i click the command link i wanna load the hello in LastName field

Answer (score 0):

Few thing you should notice..

> In controller you have set the last name and your displaying the firstname in vf page.
>   Declaration of **contacto** must be public in order to access in vf Page.

**visual force Page**

```
   <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock id="contactFields">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" > 
          <apex:pageBlockSection id="UpdateElectrodependiente" columns="2" >
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!loadData}" reRender="contactFields" value="Cargar Datos"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockSection id="LastName" columns="2">
                 <apex:inputField label="Nombre Paciente" value="{!contacto.Lastname}"></apex:inputField>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

**controller**

```
public class ATCL_VFC058_ElectrodependienteController {
   public contact contacto {get;set;}
   public ATCL_VFC058_ElectrodependienteController() {
   this.contacto =new Contact();
}       

public void loadData(){
    this.contacto.LastName='Hello';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify [getters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm) and setters or [properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) and instantiate field, that would interact with VF page.

```
public Contact contacto {get; set;}
...
public ATCL_VFC058_ElectrodependienteController(){
    ...
    this.contacto = new Contact();
    ...
}
```